# Аппроксимация таблично заданных функций

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, статистика

Имеется таблица, в которой хранится история продаж за некоторый период времени.
Необходимо, опираясь на эту информацию, сделать предположение о продажах в следующем месяце.

Мне сказали, что это можно высчитать с помощью аппроксимации таблично заданных функций.
Можете привести примеры таких расчетов в SQL или поделиться ресурсом, где про это подробно написано?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В один запрос этого не сделать. Несколько запросов, а лучше процедуру, можно использовать. Если Вам результат надо выводить, скажем, в админку сайта, то ваще прелесть - максимум математики сделать в PHP :)

Если в двух словах, то Вам надо посчитать продажи за последние несколько месяцев, сверить их в процентном соотношении, и, используя полученный коэффициент, посчитать продажи за следущий месяц.

У нас сделано такоим образом:

Имеем данные за янв-фев-март-апр-май-июн-июл.

- Вычисляем изменение продаж янв-фев. Получаем, скажем, +3%
- Вычисляем изменение продаж фев-мар. Получаем -1%
- Берем среднестастическое от полученных цифр. Получаем +1%
- Вычисляем изменение продаж мар-апр. Получаем +3%
- Берем среднестастическое от предыдущего среднестатистического и мар-апр. Получаем +1% и +3% = +2%

ну и т.д. до конца. Главное, что все время вычисляется среднестатистическое высчитанное с учетом всех месяцев.

В конце вы получите примерный процент. И уже имея этот процент можно предположить следущий месяц.
Если анализировать много месяцев, то можно и следующие 3 месяца предполагать :)

---

Однако есть несколько моментов, которые надо учитывать.

- в рассчеты надо обязательно включать только ПОЛНЫЕ месяцы. Т.е. если бы сегодня было, скажем, 15-е число, то включать текущий мсеяц в рассчет бессмысленно.
- чем большим кол-вом данных Вы располагаете, тем "точнее" (если вообще так можно выразиться про аппроксимацию) Вы можете посчитать коэффициент. Однако минус тут в том, что полученная цифра, скорее всего (чаще всего) оказывается не значительная, и график аппроксимации может не впечатлить босса/клиента
- еще немаловажно учитывать началась ли у вас в фирме какая-либо кампания по подъему продаж. Эффективная компания. Если "да", то надо учитывать данные только за период кампании, иначе они будут нереальны. Скажем до кампании у вас было 10 продаж в месяц, а как запустилась кампания - стало 100.
  Если считать аппроксимацию с 10-ю заказами, то она скакнет аж на 300, что на самом деле нереально...

---

и еще, у вас в метках к вопросу стоит `excel`. Если Вы планируете строить графики на основе этих данных, то там можно включить `trend line` (линия тенденции), тогда ничего высчитывать не надо - график сам все покажет

---

Извините, код привести не могу: по тех. причинам не имею к нему доступа... Но участвовал в обсуждении, поэтому позволил себе Вам ответить.

Надеюсь объяснил в общих чертах.

Comment: Круто, спасибо. Интересный и развернутый ответ.

Comment: @cyadvert, получается, что у меня будет что-то типа 2 ух курсоров? 1)Один идет по продуктам 2)Идет по месяцам.

Comment: Если Вы работаете только внутри SQL сервера (т.е. делаете процедуру), то да - насклько я знаю - понадобятся два курсора. Можно чуть облегчить задачу - сделать функцию, в которую передавать товар, а уже эта функция будет высчитывать... но фактически все равно получается курсор в курсоре...

Answer (score 0):

В ответах уже упоминали диаграммы Excel с линией тренда, но это  только до 6 степени апроксимации многочленом.
Насчет VBA Excel в области апроксимации - трудно реализовывать.

Больше качественной и наглядной информации можно получить загрузив данные в MatLab или его бесплатный аналог Numpy Python.

Аппроксимирующий многочлен можно задать до 60 степени. От аппроксимирующей функции можно взять производную и этот график сравнить с проводимыми мероприятиями.

Про будущее график тоже  может рассказать, но интересней связь существующего графика с проводимыми мероприятиями. Этот анализ позволит лучше сделать заключение о будущем.

Есть интересный готовый аналог  - YouTube, который на некоторых музыкальных сайтах дает статистику просмотров, общую и дневную (производную графика).
В результате анализа дневного графика, можно сделать выводы о аудитории.

Особый интерес имеет значение и знак при квадратичной составляющей аппроксимирующего многочлена. Это значение количественно характеризует выпуклость или вогнутость кривой продаж, а значит и тенденции в ближайшем будущем.

Хорошую информативность, в виде семейства кривых, имеет суммарный график или график аппроксимации, где по оси X расположены дни недели.

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос из области статистики и машинного обучения. В данном случае нужно работать с временными рядами и учитывать как минимум следующие принципиальные моменты:

1. Если динамика объемов продаж (зависимость объемов от времени) нелинейная, то любой линейный тренд будет бесполезен.
2. Если присутствует сезонность, то ее игнорирование обратно приведет к неверным выводам.
3. Сглаживанием полиномами высоких степеней гарантированно приводит к проблеме переобучения, т.е. будет получена красивая картинка, хорошо соответствующая историческим данным, но о будущем она ничего не скажет.